# Terraform azurerm provider count and csvdecode

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm

I'm trying to populate NSG rules from a CSV file.

CSV file:

```
name,priority,direction,access,protocol,source_port_range,destination_port_range,destination_port_ranges,source_address_prefix,destination_address_prefix,resource_group_name,network_security_group_name
allowindatasubnet,600,inbound,allow,*,*,*,,192.168.3.0/24,*,resourcegroup1,networksecgroup1
allowinremote,700,inbound,allow,*,*,,"3389,22",192.168.1.128/27,*,resourcegroup1,networksecgroup1
denyinall,1000,inbound,deny,*,*,*,,*,*,resourcegroup1,networksecgroup1
```

tf file:

```
locals {
  network_security_group_rules = csvdecode(file("/csvfile.csv"))
}
```

```
resource "azurerm_network_security_rule" "network_security_rule_WL1" {

  count = length(local.network_security_group_rules)

  name                        = local.network_security_group_rules[count.index].name
  priority                    = local.network_security_group_rules[count.index].priority
  direction                   = local.network_security_group_rules[count.index].direction
  access                      = local.network_security_group_rules[count.index].access
  protocol                    = local.network_security_group_rules[count.index].protocol
  source_port_range           = local.network_security_group_rules[count.index].source_port_range
  destination_port_range      = local.network_security_group_rules[count.index].destination_port_range
  destination_port_ranges     = [local.network_security_group_rules[count.index].destination_port_ranges]
  source_address_prefix       = local.network_security_group_rules[count.index].source_address_prefixyes
  destination_address_prefix  = local.network_security_group_rules[count.index].destination_address_prefix
  resource_group_name         = local.network_security_group_rules[count.index].resource_group_name
  network_security_group_name = local.network_security_group_rules[count.index].network_security_group_name

}
```

This works fine without the *destination_port_ranges* attribute within the nsg rule resource block, but when I add it in I get an error:

`Error: "destination_port_ranges": conflicts with destination_port_range`

I understand that I need to use one argument or the other, but can anyone help me with the syntax or suggest changes that I can make allowing me to keep the same CSV format?

Also is my config correct for specifying a list of ports for the destination_port_ranges argument?

UPDATE:
I tried the following which was suggested by a friend but this threw up the same exception.

```
destination_port_range      = local.network_security_group_rules[count.index].destination_port_range != "" ? local.network_security_group_rules[count.index].destination_port_range : null
destination_port_ranges     = local.network_security_group_rules[count.index].destination_port_ranges != "" ? split(",", local.network_security_group_rules[count.index].destination_port_ranges) : null
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said that you just need one argument, not both. As I see, all your destination port is a list or the character `*` and it means a range. Let's see the description of the argument `destination_port_ranges` and `destination_port_range`:

> destination_port_range - (Optional) Destination Port or Range. Integer
> or range between 0 and 65535 or * to match any. This is required if
> destination_port_ranges is not specified.

> destination_port_ranges - (Optional) List of destination ports or port
> ranges. This is required if destination_port_range is not specified.

You use a list of destination ports or port ranges, so you just need to set the argument `destination_port_ranges` in the csv file for the network security rules.

Update:

You can use a module for the rules, the module is used to decide use which attribute for each rule:

**./main.tf**

```
locals {
  network_security_group_rules = csvdecode(file("/csvfile.csv"))
}

module "rules" {
    source = "./modules/rules"

    count = length(local.network_security_group_rules)
    rule = local.network_security_group_rules[count.index]
}
```

**./modules/rules/main.tf**

```
variable "rule" {}

resource "azurerm_network_security_rule" "network_security_rule_WL1" {

  count = rule.destination_port_range == null ? 0 : 1

  name                        = local.network_security_group_rules[count.index].name
  priority                    = local.network_security_group_rules[count.index].priority
  direction                   = local.network_security_group_rules[count.index].direction
  access                      = local.network_security_group_rules[count.index].access
  protocol                    = local.network_security_group_rules[count.index].protocol
  source_port_range           = local.network_security_group_rules[count.index].source_port_range
  destination_port_range      = local.network_security_group_rules[count.index].destination_port_range
  source_address_prefix       = local.network_security_group_rules[count.index].source_address_prefixyes
  destination_address_prefix  = local.network_security_group_rules[count.index].destination_address_prefix
  resource_group_name         = local.network_security_group_rules[count.index].resource_group_name
  network_security_group_name = local.network_security_group_rules[count.index].network_security_group_name

}

resource "azurerm_network_security_rule" "network_security_rule_WL1" {

  count = rule.destination_port_ranges == null ? 0 : 1

  name                        = local.network_security_group_rules[count.index].name
  priority                    = local.network_security_group_rules[count.index].priority
  direction                   = local.network_security_group_rules[count.index].direction
  access                      = local.network_security_group_rules[count.index].access
  protocol                    = local.network_security_group_rules[count.index].protocol
  source_port_range           = local.network_security_group_rules[count.index].source_port_range
  destination_port_ranges     = [local.network_security_group_rules[count.index].destination_port_ranges]
  source_address_prefix       = local.network_security_group_rules[count.index].source_address_prefixyes
  destination_address_prefix  = local.network_security_group_rules[count.index].destination_address_prefix
  resource_group_name         = local.network_security_group_rules[count.index].resource_group_name
  network_security_group_name = local.network_security_group_rules[count.index].network_security_group_name

}
```

In this way, you can't create a rule with both two attributes not null, I mean each rule only can have one of the two attributes.

Comment: Thanks Charles, I do have a destination_port_ranges column in the CSV (line 1) with values in line 3 ("3389,22"). The error seems to suggest that nulls are required somewhere.

Comment: @Hansie No, it means you only can use one of the arguments `destination_port_range` and `destination_port_ranges` and I recommend the argument `destination_port_ranges`. That's it.

Comment: Ah ok I understand, I will have the requirement to configure single port rules when I get to production, I apologise that this was not represented by my example.

Comment: @Hansie Well, if it solves your problem, please accept it.

Comment: @Hansie I don't see you accept it. Is there something wrong?

Comment: Hi Charles, unfortunately this does not work: 

Error: Error Creating/Updating Network Security Rule "allowinremote" (NSG "xxx" / Resource Group "xxx"): network.SecurityRulesClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="SecurityRuleParameterContainsInvalidPortRanges" Message="Security rule parameter DestinationPortRanges for rule with Id /subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/xxx/securityRules/allowinremote cannot specify a '*'." Details=[]

Comment: @Hansie OK, the difference is that `destination_port_range` requires a string for port or range, but `destination_port_ranges` requires a list of ports. And they can't use both of them in one rule. You use a model, see the update.